# Is AWS Lambda function memory size variable or constant?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I created an AWS Lambda function. But I am confused about memory size. The memory size of the function is 512 MB. When 10 request comes at the same time, which scenario will be happen:

Scenario A : each function runs with 512/10 = 51,2 MB memory

Scenario B : each function runs with 512 MB memory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each execution of the function gets full access to the memory size you set when you created the function.

If there are multiple, simultaneous executions, each gets access to its own 512MB